# XSLT - how to print value through variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
 <table tableName="Something">
     <item table="Something">
       <column columnName="SomeID">someValue</column>
```

Hi everyone - the above is the structure of my XML-source.

I want to create a XSLT variable that prints the "someValue" of "SomeID" upon usage of

I can't figure out the correct xpath syntax to make this happen. I need this both for printing values and conditioning. The condition needs to test if "SomeID" is not empty - how would I path this?

I hope someone'll be able to assist.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly what you are trying to do, create the variable by

```
<xsl:variable name="SomeIDValue" select="//column[@columnName='SomeID']"/>
```

Then, you can output it by

```
<xsl:value-of select="$SomeIDValue"/>
```

And test if it is not empty by

```
<xsl:if test="$SomeIDValue != ''"><!-- What to do --></xsl:if>
```

For example, with **Example.xml** as

```
<table tableName="Something">
    <item table="Something">
        <column columnName="SomeID">someValue</column>
        <column columnName="SomeID2"/>
    </item>
</table>
```

and with **Example.xsl** as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="SomeIDValue" select="//column[@columnName='SomeID']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="SomeIDValue2" select="//column[@columnName='SomeID2']"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="$SomeIDValue != ''">SomeID is not empty and is equal to '<xsl:value-of select="$SomeIDValue"/>'.</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$SomeIDValue2 != ''">SomeID2 is not empty and is equal to '<xsl:value-of select="$SomeIDValue2"/>'.</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforming the xml with the xsl will result in output of

```
SomeID is not empty and is equal to 'someValue'.
```